# C# - Progressbar, cannot report any value or percentage

Tags: c#, winforms, progress-bar

I have a progress bar in a winform, and assigned a background worker to do some time consuming work(actually, to list bluetooth devices) in the behind. I do not know how long the work will take, neither do I know how many devices I will find, so I cannot report any value or percentage to the progressbar, I just want the progress bar to indicate that something is doing in the behind, how can I do this?

Comment: Visual Studio is a great development environment. You can use it for WinForms development as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to set progress bar's `Style` property to option `Marquee`.

Take a look at [ProgressBar documentation on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760816(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Perfect, just checked the document, 'Marquee' is just the word I am looking for, thank you!